# Errors installing libpar2 on slackware 13.37

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, installation

Could someone give me a clue as to why I might get these errors while trying to install libpar2?

```
In file included from /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/sigc++.h:23:0,
                 from libpar2.h:4,
                 from libpar2.cpp:1:
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:1557:26: error: declaration of 'typedef struct sigc::signal0<T_return, T_accumulator>::slot_list_type sigc::signal0<T_return, T_accumulator>::slot_list'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:166:1: error: changes meaning of 'slot_list' from 'struct sigc::slot_list<sigc::slot<T_return> >'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:1666:26: error: declaration of 'typedef struct sigc::signal1<T_return, T_arg1, T_accumulator>::slot_list_type sigc::signal1<T_return, T_arg1, T_accumulator>::slot_list'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:166:1: error: changes meaning of 'slot_list' from 'struct sigc::slot_list<sigc::slot<T_return, T_arg1> >'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:1777:26: error: declaration of 'typedef struct sigc::signal2<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_accumulator>::slot_list_type sigc::signal2<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_accumulator>::slot_list'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:166:1: error: changes meaning of 'slot_list' from 'struct sigc::slot_list<sigc::slot<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2> >'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:1890:26: error: declaration of 'typedef struct sigc::signal3<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_accumulator>::slot_list_type sigc::signal3<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_accumulator>::slot_list'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:166:1: error: changes meaning of 'slot_list' from 'struct sigc::slot_list<sigc::slot<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3> >'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:2005:26: error: declaration of 'typedef struct sigc::signal4<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_accumulator>::slot_list_type sigc::signal4<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_accumulator>::slot_list'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:166:1: error: changes meaning of 'slot_list' from 'struct sigc::slot_list<sigc::slot<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4> >'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:2122:26: error: declaration of 'typedef struct sigc::signal5<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_arg5, T_accumulator>::slot_list_type sigc::signal5<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_arg5, T_accumulator>::slot_list'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:166:1: error: changes meaning of 'slot_list' from 'struct sigc::slot_list<sigc::slot<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_arg5> >'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:2241:26: error: declaration of 'typedef struct sigc::signal6<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_arg5, T_arg6, T_accumulator>::slot_list_type sigc::signal6<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_arg5, T_arg6, T_accumulator>::slot_list'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:166:1: error: changes meaning of 'slot_list' from 'struct sigc::slot_list<sigc::slot<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_arg5, T_arg6> >'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:2362:26: error: declaration of 'typedef struct sigc::signal7<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_arg5, T_arg6, T_arg7, T_accumulator>::slot_list_type sigc::signal7<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_arg5, T_arg6, T_arg7, T_accumulator>::slot_list'
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:166:1: error: changes meaning of 'slot_list' from 'struct sigc::slot_list<sigc::slot<T_return, T_arg1, T_arg2, T_arg3, T_arg4, T_arg5, T_arg6, T_arg7> >'

... whole slew of warnings

make[1]: *** [libpar2.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/SBo/libpar2-0.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As far as I know sigc++-2.0 is correctly installed

```
root@a:/home/g/dnlds/libpar2# ls /usr/lib/libsigc*.so
/usr/lib/libsigc-2.0.so@
root@a:/home/g/dnlds/libpar2# pkg-config --list-all|grep -i sigc
sigc++-2.0                  libsigc++ 2 - Typesafe signal and callback system for C++
root@a:/home/g/dnlds/libpar2#
```

Answer (score 0):

No enlightenment, but this did solve my problem.  I'd never come across this site before

http://slackfind.net/en/

but they index currently 37834 slackware packages, and I got packages for both libpar2 and libsigc++, and they installed without incident.